# How can we find the total weight of a pulley apparatus?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, torque, moment-of-inertia, weight

I recently have been trying to solve this problem, which asks me to find `T3` assuming that `g = 9.8`:

[image]

My idea was to find the acceleration of the two blocks in order to calculate the apparent weights of the 40 and 26 kilogram masses, and add the apparent weights to `54*9.8`.

We can use Newton's Second Law to find `a`:

$F = ma$, so we first derive equations for `T1` and `T2`:

$T2 - 40(9.8) = 40(-a)$, so $T2 = 40(9.8 - a)$

$T1 - 26(9.8) = 26(a)$, so $T1 = 26(9.8 + a)$

Now, Torque = I * (alpha), so

$r*T2 - r*T1 = (0.5mr^2)(\frac{a}{r})$

$T2 - T1 = 0.5ma$

$40(9.8 - a) - 26(9.8 + a) = 0.5*54*a$

$14*9.8 = 93*a$

Thus, $a$ is approximately $1.475$ meters per second squared.

Now, we know that the acceleration of Block 2 is -a, and the acceleration of Block 1 is a. Thus, Block 2's apparent weight is $m * a$ = 59 and Block 1's apparent weight is $m * (-a)$ = -38.35.

Thus, the total weight of the system would be equal to

$54*9.8 + 59 - 38.35$ = 549.85.

However, this answer is wrong, and I don't know why. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: $T_1$ and $T_2$ are forces that happen to be internal to the system. Imagine holding a black box in your arms, inside of which you can't look. Would you expect the pulley moving around to change the total weight of the box?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't taken into account the actual weight of the masses.

$$W_{sys}=-(W_1+W_2+W_P)+(M_2-M_1)a=-(M_1+M_2+M_p)g+(M_2-M_1)a$$
Putting the values, You have calculated :
$$W_{sys}\approx 1155$$

Comment: After reading ChemiCalChems' comment, I thought that the weight of the apparatus would just be the sum of the weights of the two blocks and the pulley itself. However, your answer gives the correct answer. I'm a little confused as to why the term `(M2 - M1)a` is necessary, because it seems to be an internal force, meaning that it shouldn't affect the weight. If possible, can you please clarify with me what the purpose of the term `(M2-M1)a` is and why we need it?

Comment: This can be made clear as follows: Suppose You want to weight this system. What I can do is to join a spring at the string which joints with the pulley and see the expansion of spring. Use Hooke's law and note the weight of the system. What you need to calculate the force on the axle. That exactly equals to $$N=T_1+T_2+W_p$$ Proceed from here you get the exact same answer.

Comment: If there are other doubts, you might wanna post a separate question.